# Use R Loop to Bulk Download Youtube Transcripts with youtubecaption

Tags: r, youtube, tidyverse, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the `youtubecaption` library to download all the transcripts for a playlist then create a dataframe with all the results.

I have a list of the video URLs and have tried to create a for loop to pass them into the `get_caption()` function. I can only get one video's transcripts added to the df.

I've tried a few approaches:

```
vids <- as.list(mydata$videoId)

for (i in 1:length(vids)){
  vids2 <- paste("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",vids[i],sep="")
  test_transcript2 <-
    get_caption(
     url = vids2,
     language = "en",
     savexl = FALSE,
     openxl = FALSE,
     path = getwd())
  rbind(test_transcript, test_transcript2)
 }
```

Also using the column of the main dataframe:

```
captions <- sapply(mydata[,24], FUN = get_captions)
```

Is there an efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: FYI:, iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample data using `dput(x)`

Comment: @NadPat Here is an example of the main dataframe: position channelId channelTitle videoId publishedAt publishedAtSQL videoTitle videoDescription
1 UCfzP_CiebRdveD9rRZv5Ndw AllEars.net rUchC7Ufctk 2021-11-20T15:04:30Z 11/20/2021 15:04 Your Favorite Disney World Hotel Is BACK:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you do `rbind(test_transcript, test_transcript2)` *but never assign it*, so it is lost forever. When we combine that with my comment about not using the `rbind(old, newrow)` paradigm, your code might be

```r
vids <- as.list(mydata$videoId)

out <- list()
for (i in 1:length(vids)){
  vids2 <- paste("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",vids[i],sep="")
  test_transcript2 <-
    get_caption(
     url = vids2,
     language = "en",
     savexl = FALSE,
     openxl = FALSE,
     path = getwd())
  out <- c(out, list(test_transcript2))
}
alldat <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

Some other pointers:

- `for (i in 1:length(.))` can be a bad practice if this is functionalized, it's better to use `for (i in seq_along(vids))`
- we never need the index number itself, we can use `for (vid in vids)`
- we can do the `paste`ing in one shot, generally faster for R, with `for (vid in paste0("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", vids))`, and then `url=vid` in the call to `get_caption`
- with all that, it might be even simpler to use `lapply` for the whole thing:

  ```r
  path <- getwd()
  out <- lapply(paste0("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", vids),
                get_caption, language = "en", savexl = FALSE,
                openxl = FALSE, path = path)
  do.call(rbind, out)
  ```

(NB: untested.)